# nginx error_page for 502 Bad Gateway errors

Tags: nginx

Here is my server configuration:

```
    server {
            listen 0.0.0.0;
            server_name dev.host.com;

            location / {
                    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
                    proxy_redirect default;

                    error_page 502 =200 @maintenance;
            }

            location ^~ /(img|js|css)/ {
                    root /path/to/application/assets;
                    expires max;
                    break;

                    error_page 404 =302 /;
            }

            location @maintenance { 
                     root /path/to/static/offline/files;
                     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =503;
            }
    }
```

When the upstream app is not online, I am getting the default nginx 502 page for the root path (that is: `GET /`). Any idea why this is happening? I'd like the root path to respond with the maintenance page just like any other request path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The devils in the details; my `@maintenance` named location was not setup correctly. Specifically, the send argument (`$uri/`) to `try_files` was causing the problem. Here is the correct named location:

```
location @maintenance { 
    root /path/to/static/offline/files;
    try_files $uri /index.html =503;
}
```

Comment: Hah, I also followed the blog post at http://www.mjcblog.net/2011/08/nginx-custom-maintenance-page-without-redirects/ and ran into the same issue ;D

Answer (score 2):

Try setting 
proxy_intercept_errors on;
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors

Comment: No luck; tried the directive at the `http`, `server` and `proxy` location blocks

Answer (score 2):

I did this for the whole vhost:

```
server {
         (...) 
         error_page 500 502 503 504 /5xx.html;
            location /5xx.html{
                    root /www/error_pages/;
         } 
}
```

This works perfectly for me.

Comment: This does catch the root path but it's like the `try_files` directive no longer works. Every request just results in the `index.html` page so requests for images and CSS fail.